# View will not rotate

Tags: iphone, uiview, rotation

I have 2 views in my uiwindow which we will call view A and view B,

if I have view A on top view B and rotate the phone view A will not rotate unless i remove view B. Is there a way for the willrotate method to get called in view A without having to remove view B from the UIWINDOW?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that this is not possible.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html